# meaning of / operator in solr search

Tags: search, solr

I had found following list of characters had special meaning in solr search

```
+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : /
```

I understand all the characters except / operator in solr search.

Can you provide help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The special character you are talking about is not "/" but "\" . It is used for escaping characters in a Solr query . For example, while searching for (1+1):2 , you should escape it using "\" in this manner \(1\+1\)\:2 .Let me know if that helps you to understand it :) .